# How to prevent React from rendering the entire array when I append more items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of 30 unique options that I use to render 30 SVGs.

There is a button that adds 30 more unique options to the array each time it's clicked. When the 30 new options are added, React will re-render all 60 SVGs instead of just rendering the 30 new ones.

This is a problem because it's causing the frame rate to drop and makes the browser stutter. The problem gets worse and worse as there are more SVGs in the array.

I want to know how I can get React to only render the newly added 30 SVGs and not re-render everything in the array.

I even added a unique key to each SVG.

Here's my code:

```
import generateRandomSVG from "../randomGenerator";
import SVGElement from "./SVGElement";
import Button from "./button";

const getSVGs = (num) => {
  let avatarArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    avatarArray.push(generateRandomSVG());
  }

  return avatarArray;
};

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    svgs: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    //render 30 SVGs when the component first loads
    this.setState({
      svgs: getSVGs(30)
    });

    console.log(this.state.avatars);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    //when user clicks on button, add 30 more SVGs
    const moreSVGs = getSVGs(30);
    this.setState({
      svgs: this.state.svgs.concat(moreSVGs)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add 30 more SVGs </Button>

        {this.state.svgs.map((SVGObject) => {
          const key = SVGObject.uniqueKey;
          return (
            <div key={key}>
              <SVGElement {...SVGObject.options} />
            </div>
          );
        })}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is there a max number of SVGs that you render or do you add 30 SVGs *whenever* the button is clicked?

Comment: why dont you keep track of the start and end where you wanna render the items then just map over those?

Comment: @entersudonym There's no max. Actually, I want to eventually allow infinite scrolling. The button is just there for question simplicity.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this... can you create a simple demo of the problem on https://codesandbox.io/ please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of holding all your svgs in one array, make svgs array hold arrays where each array holds 30 svgs.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    svgs: svgs.push(getSVGs(30))
  });
}

handleClick = () => {
  const moreSVGs = getSVGs(30);
  const updatedSVGs = this.state.svgs.push(moreSVGs)
  this.setState({
    svgs: updatedSVGs
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add 30 more SVGs </Button>

      {this.state.svgs.forEach((svgBatch) => {
         svgBatch.map((SVGObject) => {
           const key = SVGObject.uniqueKey;
           return (
             <div key={key}>
               <SVGElement {...SVGObject.options} />
             </div>
           );
        })}
      })

    </div>
  );
}
```

This way you iterate over a batch of 30 svgs and create a compoment for each batch.
After this you can create a check in the shouldComponentUpdate method in your SVGElement to check if the new props differ from the currentones. That's how you prevent the rerendering.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
 //I don't know what your SVGObject.options contain so you will have to change
 //the check a liitle but I think you get the idea
  if (JSON.stringify(this.props.options.svgArray) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.options.svgArray)) {
    return false;
  }
}
```